# Keep getting error on unknown property on annotation when using api-platform

Tags: symfony, annotations, api-platform.com

I'm using api platform with symfony 4.  Trying to use a DTO for output on a class and following the docs (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/).

My class looks something like this:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\DTO\ElementDTO;

/**
 * Elements
 * @ORM\Table(name="elements")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource(
 *    inputClass=false,
 *    outputClass=ElementDTO::class
 *   )
 */
class Elements
{
}
```

However, I'm getting an error that looks like this:

```
Unknown property "inputClass" on annotation "ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource".
```

I searched the source code for api platform and could find no reference to inputClass or outputClass.  Is the method in the docs deprecated or not yet implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `inputClass` and `outputClass` are both in **v2.4.0-beta1** only, and I think you use **2.3.6** since this is the latest stable release AFAIK.

See this commit : https://github.com/api-platform/core/commit/cb5421abdb19392ac225909f63cf8677583cedd3

Try to use the beta version (or `dev-master`) in your code and see if it works